# Efficient use of gears - OpenShift

Tags: openshift, openshift-gears

I have to deploy a Java EE app and am using Openshift for it. 
Since i am new to it so i wanted to ask
 - How I can efficiently use the OpenShift gears. 
 - Whether the Load balancer be allotted a single gear alone or how?
 - Is scaling recommended for 3 gears?
Thank u in advance. Sorry if asked some stupid questions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are after can be found on the Openshift Docs - https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-scaling.html#creating-a-scalable-application. Initially the HAProxy will run together with the webapp on the first gear, but once three gears are reached the HAProxy will take up the whole machine. Or to quote the docs:

> The first web gear in a scaling application has HAProxy installed, but
>   also your web application. Once you scale to 3 gears, the web gear
>   that is collocated with HAProxy is turned off, to allow HAProxy more
>   resources to route traffic. Here’s a diagram of your scalable app. If
>   you scale down back to 2 gears or less, the web cartridge on your
>   first gear is started again.

Whether scaling makes sense in your case depends on your usecase and whether you for example use other cartridges (like a database) as well, which will also get their own gear. Most likely you will gain by scaling, but hard to say w/o specifics.